# Using @Qualifier based on @Inject field CDI

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi, qualifiers

I'm having trouble with CDI conditional 
injection to use a kind of Strategy in EJB's injections.

My actual scenario is that:

```
public class someManagedBean {

    @Inject 
    @MyOwnQualifier(condition = someBean.getSomeCondition()) // not work because someBean is not already injected at this point
    private BeanInterface myEJB;

    @Inject
    SomeBean someBean;
}

@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface MyOwnQualifier {
    SomeCondition condition();
}

public class BeanInterfaceFactory {
    @Produces
    @MyOwnQualifier(condition = RoleCondition.ADMIN) 
    public BeanInterface getBeanInterfaceEJBImpl() {
        return new BeanInterfaceEJBImpl();
    }
}

public enum RoleCondition {
    ADMIN("ADMIN User");
}
```

Ok, scenario explained. Now the problem is that I need to get the value 
from `someBean.getSomeCondition()` that returns a `RoleCondition`, necessary for my `@MyOwnQualifier`.
But at this time someBean is not already injected by CDI.

How I can make this line to work?

```
@Inject 
@MyOwnQualifier(condition = someBean.getSomeCondition()) // not work because some is not already injected at this point
private BeanInterface myEJB;
```

How is the right way to dynamically inject beans using qualifiers based on another injection's property value?

Comment: I don't really see how this can ever work since annotations are compile-time things, and someBean.getSomeCondition() evaluates at runtime. I'd more think you want to create a producer which can conditionally provide an instance. https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html/producermethods.html

Comment: There is no such thing like `beforeConstruct` to evaluate some values before try to inject?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this...

```
public class someManagedBean {

    @Inject 
    @MyOwnQualifier
    private BeanInterface myEJB;
}

@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface MyOwnQualifier {
    SomeCondition condition();
}

public class BeanInterfaceFactory {

    @Inject
    SomeBean someBean

    @Produces
    @MyOwnQualifier
    public BeanInterface getBeanInterfaceEJBImpl() {
        if(someBean.getCondition()) {         
            return new BeanInterfaceEJBImpl();
        } else {
           ....
        }
    }
}

public enum RoleCondition {
    ADMIN("ADMIN User");
}
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you for help. someBean for some reason is null at this time on factory `getBeanInterfaceEJBImpl`

Comment: if is null mean that BeanInterfaceFactory isn't a cdi bean, try add @Named. Wich discovery mode are you using in beans.xml ?

Comment: Yeah, sorry for my ignorance haha, after lunch I will check if is everything alright, apparrently it will work. Thank you so much, you're the best :)

Comment: I'm glad to have helped you! ;-)

Comment: Thanks man, it worked like a charm.. I just had to replace `new BeanInterfaceEJBImpl()` to `CDI.current().select(BeanInterfaceEJBImpl.class).get();`